# Error: Could not find or load main class TestClient

Tags: java, class, websocket, socket.io

I'm attempting to build a HelloWord websocket client with the example code provided here: https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/blob/master/examples/basic/BasicExample.java

The goal is to connect to a Flask server that uses: https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat The client in python I've built works fine, however I also need to build a java client.

I've seen a lot of different solutions that suggest adding a `-cp` during compiling, but still get the same message `Error: Could not find or load main class TestClient` What am I doing wrong?

I'm using this script to compile & run.

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac TestClient.java -cp /home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat/*.jar:*:.:./
echo "exitcode:$?"
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java TestClient
```

Here's the output:

```
exitcode:0
Error: Could not find or load main class TestClient
```

### TestClient.java

```
import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;
import io.socket.IOCallback;
import io.socket.SocketIO;
import io.socket.SocketIOException;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class TestClient implements IOCallback {
    private SocketIO socket;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        try {
            new TestClient();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public TestClient() throws Exception {
        socket = new SocketIO();
        socket.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", this);

        // Sends a string to the server.
        socket.send("Hello Server");

        // Sends a JSON object to the server.
        socket.send(new JSONObject().put("key", "value").put("key2",
                "another value"));

        // Emits an event to the server.
        socket.emit("event", "argument1", "argument2", 13.37);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
        System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
        System.out.println("an Error occured");
        socketIOException.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnect() {
        System.out.println("Connection established");
    }

    @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

`Error: Could not find or load main class TestClient`

indicates that the Java launcher can't find/load the class file `TestClient.class`.

To load it properly both the class file itself and the jar file socketio.jar need to be on the class path. So please try

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp .:socketio.jar TestClient`

or

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp /home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat:/home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat/socketio.jar TestClient`

Comment: Alas neither worked:
erm@erm76:~/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp /home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat/ TestClient
Error: Could not find or load main class TestClient
erm@erm76:~/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp . TestClient
Error: Could not find or load main class TestClient

Comment: Just to make sure: There _is_ the class file TestClient.class in the directory /home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat?

Comment: Yes `TestClient.class` exists :)

Comment: I revised my answer after reading your conversation with Pat. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  I don't know why this works: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -cp .:socketio.jar TestClient` but it does.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer should work if the file was missing.

But before that, can you please check if the Java file was compiled as it is being run through shell ???

if not please **compile the java file**

```
javac TestClient.java
```

if you are in the path where TestClient.java is present
or provide the full path eg. `javac /app/javafiles/TestClient.java`

Comment: this works:`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac TestClient.java -cp /home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat/*.jar` this does not: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac TestClient.java 
TestClient.java:2: error: package io.socket does not exist
import io.socket.IOAcknowledge;`

Comment: You need to either keep java files with package io.socket class in the same path as TestClient.java or add the JAR where this package exists while compiling the java file `-cp /home/erm/git/Flask-SocketIO-Chat/*.jar`

Comment: Compile only once i.e use "javac" only once and from the next time use only java.

Comment: I agree, and that's what I have:
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 erm erm 153810 Sep 17 00:29 socketio.jar
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 erm erm   2377 Sep 17 17:29 TestClient.class
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 erm erm   1916 Sep 17 00:44 TestClient.java

Comment: Seriously I don't get it.  Here's the [zip of the dir](http://the-erm.com/test-client.zip) I'm working with feel free to test it on your system.  It compiles just fine, but no matter what combination of `-cp` flags I add it just won't run.  If you're concerned about socketio.jar being malicious feel free to build your own from https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client